# Docker Postgres with windows share

Tags: windows, postgresql, docker, mount

I migrated from Linux to Windows and tried to setup a postgres container with a mounted directory (copied from my Linux install) containing the database.

This does not work.

- Windows mounts are always owned by root
- Postgres does not run under root

How to get this unholy combination to work?

Comment: You can't use the data directory from a Linux installation with a Postgres server running on Windows.

Comment: No. It is a Windows host, and Linux postgres container. The directory was originally copied from a Linux machine, but that is, other than historical context, unimportant.

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide much details so it is difficult to tell what actually went wrong. However there is a known issue with Postgres setup on Windows Docker using a windows mount for database data files. In that case, running docker logs will show something along the following lines

```
waiting for server to start....FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has wrong ownership
HINT:  The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory.
 stopped waiting
pg_ctl: could not start server
```

Unfortunately there is no way to overcome this issue so you cannot use Windows mount, see [Postgres Data has wrong ownership](https://forums.docker.com/t/data-directory-var-lib-postgresql-data-pgdata-has-wrong-ownership/17963/31). You may use docker volumes in order to make database data indipendent from docker postgres container, using the following commands

```
docker create -v /var/lib/postgresql/data --name PostgresData alpine
docker run -p 5432:5432 --name yourPostgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=yourPassword -d --volumes-from PostgresData postgres
```

You may find a more thoroughful explanation at [Setup Postgresql on Windows with Docker](https://elanderson.net/2018/02/setup-postgresql-on-windows-with-docker/)